# How to display ALL contents and output to a file

Tags: r

In R, I have a data.frame as below. I tried to use capture the output and save it to a file. But I could not display the whole content of the files. How do I capture ALL content and save it to a file?

```
out<-capture.output(dat)
cat(out, file="foo.txt",sep="\n")
```

In the "foo.txt" file:

```
GRanges object with 64 ranges and 1 metadata column:
       seqnames          ranges strand |              score
          <Rle>       <IRanges>  <Rle> |          <numeric>
    24     chrI     54465-54751      * |  0.105508391829195
   180    chrII   269805-269999      * |  0.193550118387652
   267    chrII   484793-485071      * |  0.104396728326273
   273    chrII   491317-491643      * |  0.156685421683233
   534   chrIII   304919-305173      * |  0.213069755405916
   ...      ...             ...    ... .                ...
  4115    chrXV   840371-840675      * |  0.108179402969038
  4203    chrXV 1088341-1088708      * |  0.105422580208723
  4426   chrXVI   616105-616427      * |  0.096156726436109
  4477   chrXVI   732385-732655      * |  0.115328817564031
  4518   chrXVI   866791-867117      * | 0.0800621091052711
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with a GRanges object, but you can try:

```
sink('foo.txt')
print(out, n=5000)
sink()
```